# spring hibernate obtain lock on the whole db

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, tomcat, locking

i need to run script which updates all tables in production database, so i need to get lock of all database on the only application server. How to do that? I'm using spring, tomcat, oracle and hibernate in my app.

Answer (score 2):

What people usually do for this is to `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE x FROM PUBLIC` and then force other connections closed, or modify the `pg_hba.conf` file and reload the configuration to prevent the unwanted logins.